# Drupal 7: Query custom content type with no results

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am attempting to query a custom content type called players (machine name) in a Drupal 7 module and it seemed to be working fine up until an hour ago. Nothing has changed on my side but now the 'Select' works, when I remove all the conditions,  but when I add a fieldCondition I am getting empty results.

Here is my query:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'players')
  ->fieldCondition('field_email_address', 'value', $email_address)
  ->fieldCondition('field_password', 'value', $password)
  ->range(0, 1);

$results = $query->execute();
```

I have verified and reverified the bundle name, each machine name for the fields, and the values being passed in, but when I dump and die the query results, they come up empty.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: this missing `$query->execute();` , normal ? https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/howtos/how-to-use-entityfieldquery-for-drupal-7

Comment: I have that just didn't add it to the post, but edited it to include it.

Comment: did you dump values $email_address and $password ? if you make sql request with couple values you have results ?

Comment: It seems like a permission issue. When I am logged in as admin it works, when I am not, I cannot added the fieldConditions to the query. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, for some stupid reason you can query a whole database as an unauthenticated user but not with a where clause so you need to add ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1)) before the ->range(0,1). Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Yes, you saved my life :)

Also true for Drupal 8 entityQuery...

Comment: Still, I must admit that it seems more a workaround than a proper solution, so I asked [a question on drupal stackexchange](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/290481/entityquery-for-anonymous-user).